# Response data in postman has some additional characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using postgresql and node to create a crud application. I am having trouble sending post requests to the server. I tried testing the response data on postman, but the json data has some additional characters.

I have tried inserting data directly in the application and it works. I also tried using x-www-form-urlencoded and it works. The problem arises when i try posting using raw in postman.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const pg = require("pg");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const connectionString = "postgres://postgres:dennis@localhost:5432/School";
const pool = new pg.Pool({
    connectionString: connectionString
});

// app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("not able to connect " + err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        client.query("select * from student where id= $1", [1], (err, result) => {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            res.status(200).send(result.rows);
        })
    })
})

app.get('/students', (req, res, next) => {
    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error while connecting ' + err)
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        client.query("select * from student", (err, result) => {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.status(400).send(err)
            }
            res.status(200).send(result.rows)
        })
    })
})

app.post('/add', (req, res, next) => {
    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(400).send('could not connect ' + err);
        }

        client.query("insert into student (id, name, rollnumber) values($1, $2, $3)", [req.body.id, req.body.name, req.body.rollnumber], (err, result) => {
            done();
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }

            res.json({
                message: req.body
            })
        })
    })
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('working');
})
```

This is what i get from the req.body in postman. The json data has some funny characters.

```
{
    "message": {
        "{\r\n        \"id\": \"1\",\r\n        \"name\": \"jjjj\",\r\n        \"rollnumber\": \"7788\"\r\n    }": ""
    }
}
```

This is what I expect to get `{"id": "1", "name": "jjj", "rollnumber": "7788"}`

Comment: kindly share the postman screenshot

Comment: https://ibb.co/ssG0hbv. Here is the link to the image

Comment: I think, you are sending data using JSON.stringify().  Please make sure to parse it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please change the conent-type of the request. Now you are sending it as text format but you need to send it as json format.

[image]

Comment: undefined:1
[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Query.client.query [as callback] (E:\nodepost\app.js:75:30)
    at Query.handleReadyForQuery (E:\nodepost\node_modules\pg\lib\query.js:125:10)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (E:\nodepost\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:244:19)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code,

`req.body` is not a `JSON` string anymore. So you first need to **`stringify` and `parse`** it.

```
res.json({
        message: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))
})
```

Answer (score -1):

In postman while sending json request body choose **application/json**. you are using text now.